# REST response gets cached for guest user requests

Tags: caching, 8

I've implemented kind of a page hit counter as REST request. The article page renders a JS into the page that does a jQuery.getJSON to the REST resource later.

So far that works fine. The page is delivered from cache (X-Drupal-Cache:"HIT") and the browser does an extra request to the REST resource (/api/v1/check/l/1?_format=json).

Unfortunately the REST handler is not called for guest user views. Instead, Drupal delivers the cached response. It only works for authenticated users.

For guest I get

```
Cache-Control:"must-revalidate, no-cache, private"
X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache:"UNCACHEABLE"
```

BUT:

```
X-Drupal-Cache:"HIT"
```

And the REST handler is not executed. My REST response is

```
return (new ResourceResponse($rc))->addCacheableDependency(null);
```

Thanks

Comment: Put options: no_cache: TRUE into your rest route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the page cache for anonymous users, which works independently from the dynamic cache.

You can disable it with this command:

```
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
```

You can trigger this anywhere in your code and it will be valid for any response  you send for the request. So this should also work for a REST response.

Comment: Yes, works! Thanks. I have inserted that trigger right before my ResourceResponse return, now it invalidates the page cache for the REST request only. Exactly what I need. ThumbsUp

Answer (score 5):

I have a resource post (for anonymous).
The above answers Didn't help me.

The following did :

```
$response = new ModifiedResourceResponse($result);
return $response;
```

Read more at [ModifiedResourceResponse()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!rest!src!ModifiedResourceResponse.php/8.2.x)

Comment: For anyone that might read this, this helped me in a GET resource as well, not just POST.

Comment: Has this always been a problem? I swear this started recently for us (around 8.5.4).

Answer (score 0):

Try add 'addCacheableDependency' to 'ResourceResponse'

```
$response = new ResourceResponse($result);
$response->addCacheableDependency($result);
return $response;
```

[Create Rest Resource for GET Method in Drupal 8](http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/create-rest-resource-for-get-method-drupal-8)