# Unable to set cache max-age on ResourceResponse

Tags: 8

I'm trying to create a REST API GET response. My class extends `ResourceBase` and this is inside its `get()` method.

```php
$response = new ResourceResponse(['time' => time()], 200);

$cache_meta_data = new CacheableMetadata();
$cache_meta_data->setCacheMaxAge(2);
$response->addCacheableDependency($page);
$response->addCacheableDependency($cache_meta_data);

return $response;
```

This will return the timestamp, but it will be cached forever until I manually clear the cache. When I run `curl 'https://mylocaldrupal.dd:8443/rest/upcoming_matches/1?_format=json' -i -k`, this is the output for the first hit.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 11 Feb 2018 17:03:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1h mod_fcgid/2.3.9
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.14
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache, private
X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache: UNCACHEABLE
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-language: en
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
X-Generator: Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org)
X-Drupal-Cache: MISS
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
   
{"time":1518368586}
```

This is the output of the second hit, after a few seconds.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 11 Feb 2018 17:04:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1h mod_fcgid/2.3.9
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.14
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache, private
X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache: UNCACHEABLE
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-language: en
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
X-Generator: Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org)
X-Drupal-Cache: HIT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json

{"time":1518368586}
```

I can't really figure it out. Drupal.org documents don't really seem to help me neither. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: See this issue [Bubbling of elements' max-age to the page's headers and the page cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2352009) and this question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207800/rest-response-gets-cached-for-guest-user-requests

Comment: @4k4 I don't want to disable the cache completely! I want to set it to X seconds.

Comment: see this example where 3600 seconds are set in a response event subscriber https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196469/anonymous-user-cache-control/196557#196557

Comment: @4k4 I tried the event subscriber solution. I do see that the cache HIT and MISSES are correct with the example. However the data itself is still cached forever.

Comment: After you've cleared the cache a request should show this header: `Expires: Mon, 12 Feb 2018 12:22:00 GMT` with a time in the future. Following requests should show a cache HIT until the Expires time is reached and there is a cache MISS with a new Expires time.

Comment: Correct, I do see that the Expires headers are correct every time in line with the HIT and MISSES. However the actual data is still returning the cached value. In this case it always returns the `time()` from the first request. Until I do a manual cache clear.

Comment: There is only one other place where responses are cached, check if this database table `cache_dynamic_page_cache` is filled after you've cleared the cache. Though this cache normally respects the cache metadata you've added to the response already.

Comment: It shows the line with from the REST interface. However I did notice the "expire" column is set to -1. This is maybe related?

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the cache metadata, for example I don't know what is in $page. Try to set only the cache max-age, nothing else.

Comment: I should have left out the $page parameter from the example. But it contains an URL parameter. Integer value of what "page" to load. Pagination like behaviour. Setting the max-age only doesn't work either.
This is what I have now: `$result = ['time' => time()]; return new ResourceResponse($result, 200);` And then the basic EventSubscriber to set the Expires header.

Comment: Now you return no cache data, which means expire -1.

Comment: Correct! If I add the cache meta data to the response, and then set the max-age and expiration in the EventSubscriber it works. I'll update my question with the solution and credit you and Berdir :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The referenced question from 4k4 describes how to disable the internal page cache completely.

To not disable but set an expiration on the anonymous/internal page cache, you can use the Expires header, just set it to a date in the future and that will be respected. That's the only thing that the internal page cache module currently respects.

See the linked core issue for more information, it's partially simply an overlook that it wasn't done before 8.0 but now it would be an API change to start respecting it and lots of things would then make Drupal uncacheable, like the language switcher block. So we'll have to be very careful with any change we make.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that indeed MaxAge is ignored. I also found the referenced issue on DO. Do you have an example on how to set the Expires header? I tried to do it but somehow it always get overridden with the 19 nov 1978 date.

Comment: This is what we do in a response event subscriber, should also work directly in the controller IMHO, FinishResponseSubcriber should only set a custom expires header if none is set yet: `$response->setExpires(new \DateTime($cache_max_age . 'sec'));`

Comment: I tried this event subscriber approach and the Expires header is correct. However the data itself seems to be cached forever. Do I need to change the Cache-Control headers as well (see original question above)