# Why aren't my rest responses being cached?

Tags: 9

I created a simple rest endpoint to test caching and I see the response updating. What is stopping it from being cached?

Here's the rest endpoint code:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\nm_base_api\Plugin\rest\resource;

use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;
use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetaData;



/**
 * This is just an example.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "test",
 *   label = @Translation("Test"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/v1/test"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class Test extends ResourceBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function get() {
    $response = new ResourceResponse(
      [
        'title' => 'test',
        'time' => time(),
      ]
    );
    $cache_meta_data = new CacheableMetadata();
    $cache_meta_data->setCacheMaxAge(2);
    $response->addCacheableDependency($cache_meta_data);

    return $response;
  }

}
```

And here's what I see in response:

```
$curl 'http://base.test:8020/api/v1/test'
{"title":"test","time":1651152255}

$ curl 'http://base.test:8020/api/v1/test'
{"title":"test","time":1651152256}

$ curl 'http://base.test:8020/api/v1/test'
{"title":"test","time":1651152257}
```

Comment: Do you just need to add the correct cache metadata to the response?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [D8: Unable to set cache max-age on ResourceResponse](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/255579/d8-unable-to-set-cache-max-age-on-resourceresponse)

Comment: That seems to be the opposite, they don't want caching but have it. I want caching but don't have it.

Comment: @Lambic - Do you see how they're added cache metadata in that post? That's what you need to do.

Comment: I've tried that, and updated the example above, still no caching happening

Comment: Might be a local dev setting disabling caching?

Comment: That's possible, so I pushed the code up to a ci instance to test there, and still encountering the same issue. Also we're running redis as a cache backend so possible it's specific to redis.

Comment: Are other pages being cached?

Comment: It's actually hard to tell because it's an api driven site with no public content, but I'll play around and see if I can test that.